What is the ghost arrow on Google Maps while navigating somewhere?
For many years I've been vexed by a secondary, ghostly arrow on Google Maps, as seen below. There's me - the blue arrow in a white circle - and a few steps ahead of me on my route, is a white arrow in a grey circle. What the heck is that?


The ghost arrow is a secondary marker along the route to help the user navigate when seeing the route ahead.
While in navigation mode, when the user manipulates the view (e.g. by dragging or pinching), a ghost arrow will be shown along the selected route. The intended purpose is to show the projected direction when the user is following the route ahead. This can be confirmed by the "Re-center" button that is only shown when the user moves the map and thus fixes the view.

Hmm. If I open a route and pan down along the route a bit, the arrow disappears. It seems to me like if that's the purpose, then it would stay no matter how far along the route I panned. But it goes away if I pan more than a little from my current position along the route. So it's just to show the projected direction....of the next 1% of the trip....? That just doesn't really make sense. If this was its purpose, it would be visible anywhere I looked on the route.
